# compare path in java

Tags: java, path

i have those paths stored in arraylist like this :

```
html/body/div/header/div/div/a/span 
html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/h2 
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1 
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span 
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span/h1
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/a/span/h1
```

i want compare each path with other, and keep at the end only the similar path ,
result that i want is like this :

```
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span
```

the java code is :

```
ArrayList<String> list_input = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> list_output = new ArrayList() ;


        list_input.add("");

         list_input.add("html/body/div/header/div/div/a/span");
    list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/h2");
    list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2");
    list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1");
    list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span");
    list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span/h1");
    list_input.add("html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/a/span/h1");

        for(int a=0; a<list_input.size(); a++)
        {
            String chemin = list_input.get(a);
            for(int b=0; b<list_input.size(); b++)
                if(a != b)
                {
                    String chemin_comparé = list_input.get(b);
                    if(chemin_comparé.indexOf(chemin) != -1 && !list_output.contains(chemin))
                        list_output.add(chemin);
                }
        }

        for(String chemin_disp: list_output)
            System.out.println(chemin_disp);
```

but this code give only this result :

```
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span
```

in fact that also

```
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a
```

must be returned but it dosnt !
please help me , and thanks in advance .

Comment: `chemin_comparé` or `chemin_compare` ?

Comment: I run your code and it returns

html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a

html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span

Comment: Your question is unclear, even after re-reading. Please clarify.

Comment: it's compared_path in english

Comment: This code works fine in my computer. Vote to close as not reproducible.

Comment: please run it again , i modified , a path , this time it'll not return it

Comment: Martin , i want to return paths that shares same parts of path :)

Comment: They all share same part of the path, `html/body/div`.

Comment: Guy In this case only html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a
html/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a/span are the longest commun part of paths

Comment: You need to decide what is the logic you want to use, i.e. what is the length of similar path that is the minimum to save the path.

Comment: By the way, `Contains()` on all the String won't work when the paths are the same length with different parts. Use `substring` to do it.

Comment: Guy , ok i'll calcule length , and then paths with same length i 'll test if one contains other ! :/ i hope it works

Comment: i think this logic will not work in this case of html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2
html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1/h1

Comment: while the result should be html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a

Comment: I know, I wrote it. Use substring for it.

Comment: ok Guy i'll try it :) , thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now that you edited here another answer:

First, to get all shared path you have to compare in a loop, cutting of the part after the last slash until there is no slash left:

```
 for(int a=0; a<list_input.size(); a++)
        {
            for(int b=0; b<list_input.size(); b++) {
                String chemin = list_input.get(a);
                if(a != b)
                {
                    String chemin_comparé = list_input.get(b);
                    while(true) {
                        if(chemin_comparé.indexOf(chemin) != -1 && !list_output.contains(chemin))
                            list_output.add(chemin);
                        if(chemin.contains("/")) {
                            chemin = chemin.substring(0, chemin.lastIndexOf("/"));
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

So basicly when comparing the following:

- html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2
- html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1

You have to check:

1. Does

   - html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2
     contain
   - html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h1
2. Does

   - html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2
     contain
   - html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a
3. Does

   - html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2
     contain
   - html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li

....

13. Does

    - html/body/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li/a/h2
      contain
    - html

The Code I posted above does exactly that, allways cutting of the last slash until there is none left.

However, now you actually have ALL path that are equal,
including just "html"

since you only want the "longest" equal path, you can simply filter the output list again, removing elements that are substrings / contained in other list-elements:

```
final ArrayList<String> filteredOutputList = new ArrayList<>();
for (String string1 : list_output) {
    boolean stringIsContainedInOtherString = false;
    for (String string2 : list_output) {
        if(!string2.equals(string1) && string2.contains(string1)) {
                stringIsContainedInOtherString = true;
                break;
        }
    }
    if(!stringIsContainedInOtherString && !filteredOutputList.contains(string1)) {
        filteredOutputList.add(string1);
    }
}

for(String filteredOutput: filteredOutputList)
    System.out.println(filteredOutput);
```

Comment: thaaaaanks a lot , ur method is logic and it works in my case ! i appreciate your explanation.